# sending email more than once at a time

Tags: c#, database, oledb

I want to send an email to more than 1 person. Why this code is showing this message: "the parameter'to' can not be an empty string Parameter name:to" ?

```
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand command1 = new OleDbCommand();
command1.Connection = connection;
string cq = "Select Email From student where S_ID in(select S_ID FROM studentbook where DateDiff('d',[Issue_Date], NOW())=31) ";
command1.CommandText = cq;
OleDbDataAdapter da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command1);
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
da1.Fill(dt1);

foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
{
    string email = row["Email"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("Trying to send email ");

    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("cuet.library12@gmail.com", email))
    {
        mm.Subject = "Attention please,renew your book";
        mm.Body = string.Format("1 month over,you should renew or return the book");

        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        credentials.UserName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        credentials.Password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = credentials;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
        MessageBox.Show("Email sent successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should check for empty values from your database result. Obviously there exists a record with an empty email address.

Comment: Also you should consider adding multiple recipients to `Bcc` instead of `To` which will allow you to send the message only once.

Comment: You should also dispose the `SmtpClient`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the email address from the datatable, do a check to see if the email is not empty. If it is empty continue to the next row.

```
string email = row["Email"].ToString();
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) || value.Trim().Length == 0)
{
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add at least one recipient:

```
mm.To.Add("email@example.com");
```

You can also add multiple recipients.

Comment: This is what the OP does using the constructor [MailMessage(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14k9fb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: i do not understand where i have to change my code .please if you edit my code it will be better for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("addres1@emailserver.com"));
mm.To.Add(new MailAddress("addres2@emailserver.com"));
```

Don't forget to add an address where you sending from:

```
mm.From = new MailAddress("addres3@emailserver.com"));
```

If you will send e-mails in BCC you can use:

```
mm.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("addres1@emailserver.com"));
mm.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress("addres2@emailserver.com"));
```

<sup>Source: [msdn.microsoft.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx)</sup>

Comment: This is what the OP does using the constructor [MailMessage(string, string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14k9fb7t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: It might be better to add these to the bcc field, in the interests of privacy.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the email that you are getting from datatable might be null or empty. So make sure to check for null/empty string before proceeding with sending the email.

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
    continue;
```

Also, If you are sending the same email to multiple recipients, then instead of doing everything in the foreach loop, add the recipients in `mm.To.Add("email address to send to");` and then finally send the email.

```
connection.Open();
varcommand1 = new OleDbCommand();
command1.Connection = connection;
varcq = "Select Email From student where S_ID in(select S_ID FROM studentbook where DateDiff('d',[Issue_Date], NOW())=31) ";
command1.CommandText = cq;
varda1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(command1);
vardt1 = new DataTable();
da1.Fill(dt1);
using (var mm = new MailMessage())
{
    foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
    {
        varemail = row["Email"].ToString();
        if(string.IsNullOrWhitespace(email))
            continue;
        mm.Bcc.Add(email);   
    }
    mm.From.Add("SenderEmailAddress");   
    mm.Subject = "Attention please,renew your book";
    mm.Body = string.Format("1 month over,you should renew or return the book");

    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    var credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
    credentials.UserName = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    credentials.Password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = credentials;
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Send(mm);
}
```